# 2d histogram java or pipe output from pig to another script

Tags: java, charts, pipe, apache-pig, knowm-xchart

I need to create a 2d histogram using pig. I have created a standard histogram already using a UDF in java and xchart by xeiam (http://xeiam.com/xchart/). However I cannot find any java library for 2d histogram (I have checked probably about 20 libraries).

If this does not exist (which I found weird) is there any way to send output from pig to some other script e.g gnuplot or R? I don't want to save the data to file and upload in order to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Python wrapper and use something like matplotlib/numpy to generate plots/histograms: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch09.html